# Searching for a reference on Wishart matrices

Tags: reference-request, random-matrices

Do you happen to know a reference for exercise 2.1.18 from page 20 of Zeitouni's et al textbook:
http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~zeitouni/cupbook.pdf
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exercise develops the proof of the Marchenko-Pastur distribution. Worked out proofs along similar lines can be found at various places, some pointers follow. None of these take precisely the same steps as in the exercise, but I presume once you have understood one of these worked out proofs you're done:

1. https://www.math.wisc.edu/~valko/courses/833/2009f/lec_6_7.pdf
2. https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/386/Wigner.pdf
3. https://ion.nechita.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/using-rm-in-qit.pdf

Comment: I found the paper itself of Marcenko - Pastur: http://ipgold.epfl.ch/~leveque/Matrix/marchenko_pastur.pdf